# Уменьшить количество тиков времени на оси абсцисс

Tags: python, время, matplotlib

Нужно построить в браузере график зависимости некоторого ряда данных от времени, они хранятся в базе данных sqlite3. Формат времени в базе данных такой:

```
2021-04-28 03:47:36.957
2021-04-28 03:47:46.957
2021-04-28 03:47:56.957
2021-04-28 03:48:07.007
2021-04-28 03:48:17.006
```

Строю график с помощью следующего кода

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from dateutil import parser
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
style.use('fivethirtyeight')

mpl.use('WebAgg')

conn = sqlite3.connect(r"C:\part80.db")
c = conn.cursor()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
def graph_data():
        c.execute('SELECT ch0, sample_time FROM samples_view DESC LIMIT 1000')
        data = c.fetchall()
        ch0 = []
        sample_time = []
        
        dates = [date2num(t) for t in sample_time]
        for row in data:
                ch0.append(row[0])
                dates.append(row[1])
        print(dates)
        fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=60)
        fig.tight_layout()
        plt.plot_date(dates, ch0,'-')
        plt.show()
graph_data()
```

Но на готовом графике получается кровавое месиво

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно уменьшить количество подписей? Можно ли сделать так, чтобы они были адаптивными? Например чтобы подписи с часами, минутами и секундами появлялись только при увеличении графика? Спасибо.

UPD: Matlpotlib сам ставит нормальное количество тиков, но не делал этого из-за того, что date2num была вызвана в неправильном месте

Comment: По настройке временной оси было в теме по `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946371/editing-the-date-formatting-of-x-axis-tick-labels-in-matplotlib и тут https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_major_formatter.html

Answer (score 0):

```
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::2])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]